# Summary/reference documentation on Scala standard library types

Tags: api, scala, documentation, libraries

Details on the packages/types is in the [Scala API documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html) on scala-lang.org. But that's organised by class and I (as a Scala neophyte) find it difficult to locate the exact data type I need and work out what operation are supported on what (especially in the huge and powerful scala.collections.* tree).

Is there an online or dead-tree resource that either presents this reference information more usably, or guides the reader through the library?

Alternatively, maybe I just need to be informed how to use the existing Scala API doc website more effectively.

Any advice on effective use of the standard Scala library gratefully received!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the collections in particular, there's a very good overview available here: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html

Written by Martin Odersky himself :)

Comment: There is also http://www.decodified.com/scala/collections-api.xml for a nice view of the hierarchy.